# Unable to target any CloudFoundry cloud in VMC - Error (JSON 404): <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF/

Tags: cloud-foundry

I've been attempting to connect to any (My microcloud instance as well as simply api.cloudfoundry.com) cloud for the past hours with no success. I have seen others ask about connection issues, but it seems like my particular situation was never addressed.

When I attempt to connect to either my microcloud instance or the api.cloudfoundry.com cloud I always get this error:

**Host is not available or is not valid: '[CLOUD_URL]'

Would you like see the response? [yN]: y**

Error (JSON 404): <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF/...

Additional Info:

- Sitting behind company firewall
- Configured the microcloud to use the proxy settings
- I can ping my microcloud's domain and get a response, IP is the same as that configured in microcloud instance
- I attempted to modify my hosts file to point *.[micro_cloud_name].cloudfoundry.me to the IP specified. No success.
- I get a valid response when attempting to access api.[micro_cloud_name].cloudfoundry.me/info

Does anyone have a clue what I'm missing here? Or at least how I can see the entire untruncated error response?

Any bit of information would be greatly appreciated. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Any luck getting this resolved?

Answer (score 1):

Did you get this figured out? It sounds like your corporate network may use an HTTP proxy. If so, you'll need to set the `http_proxy` environment variable for vmc to work. Your network administrator should have details about how to set the environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `vmc -t` to see the http trace. This will help you diagnose the problem I guess.